# How to get the string value from a js code

Tags: php, javascript, preg-match, urldecode

I want to get the string value and later to use `urldecode()`.

Javascript

```
document.write(unescape('%46%43%20%42%72%61%73%6f%76%20%76%73%2e%20%43%53%4d%53%20%49%61%73%69'));
```

PHP

```
$string = "document.write(unescape('%46%43%20%42%72%61%73%6f%76%20%76%73%2e%20%43%53%4d%53%20%49%61%73%69'));";

preg_match('/document.write(unescape(\'.*\'));/', $string,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

but this return `array(0) { }`

Comment: you would have to escape the parethesis `(` `)` inside the regex pattern. `\(` `\)`

Comment: result: array(1) { [0]=> string(98) "document.write(unescape('%46%43%20%42%72%61%73%6f%76%20%76%73%2e%20%43%53%4d%53%20%49%61%73%69'));" }

Comment: Put `.*` as `(.*)` in the regex pattern. You will get the string in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$string = "document.write(unescape('%46%43%20%42%72%61%73%6f%76%20%76%73%2e%20%43%53%4d%53%20%49%61%73%69'));";
preg_match('/document.write\(unescape\(\'(.*)\'\)\);/', $string,$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
string '%46%43%20%42%72%61%73%6f%76%20%76%73%2e%20%43%53%4d%53%20%49%61%73%69' (length=69)
```